# Ordering that maximizes pair-wise matches between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, matching

Let's say we have two one-dimensional numpy arrays `v1` and `v2`. The arrays are of equal length. The dtype of the arrays is '<U1' in this case. The two arrays may or may not have common items. In each array, all items are unique.

I want to write function `get_maximum_match_order` that:

- Takes `v1` and `v2` as inputs.
- Returns an index array that can be then used to re-order `v2`. The re-ordered `v2` should then have maximal pair-wise matches with `v1`.

### Example cases:

#### Case 1

Here the arrays match each other perfectly already, so the order will be neutral. `v2` will remain the same after the order is applied.

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])

v2 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([0, 1, 2])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['A', 'B', 'C']`

#### Case 2

In this case all items are not present in both arrays. After the order has been applied to `v2`, items 'A' and 'B' will match.

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'C', 'B'])

v2 = np.array(['B', 'A', 'E'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([1, 2, 0])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['A', 'E', 'B'])`

#### Case 3

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])

v2 = np.array(['C', 'B', 'A'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([2, 1, 0])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])`

#### Case 4

Here the arrays don't have any common items, so the ordering will be neutral.

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])

v2 = np.array(['D', 'E', 'F'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([0, 1, 2])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['D', 'E', 'F'])`

#### Case 5

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])

v2 = np.array(['A', 'C', 'B'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([0, 2, 1])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])`

#### Case 6

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'G', 'B'])

v2 = np.array(['B', 'F', 'A'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([2, 1, 0])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['A', 'F', 'B'])`

#### Case 7

```py
v1 = np.array(['A', 'G', 'B', 'C', 'E'])

v2 = np.array(['B', 'F', 'A', 'E', 'C'])

order = get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2)
```

`order -> np.array([2, 1, 0, 4, 3])`

`v2[order] -> np.array(['A', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'E'])`

I've tried experimenting with numpy's intersect1d but haven't been able to nail this down perfectly.

Comment: So, how did you manage to do this imperfectly?

Comment: What if the input is ABCBA and BCACB?

Comment: The items in the arrays are assumed unique so those inputs wouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find pairs and align them and then distribute rest elements (indexes) any way you like.

```py
from contextlib import suppress
import numpy as np

def index(vs, v):
    with suppress(IndexError):
        return np.where(vs == v)[0][0]

def get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2):
    ixs = [index(v1, v) for v in v2]
    it = iter(set(range(len(v1))) - set(ixs))
    return np.array([next(it) if ix is None else ix for ix in ixs])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = np.array(['A', 'G', 'B', 'C', 'E'])
    v2 = np.array(['B', 'F', 'A', 'E', 'C'])
    print(get_maximum_match_order(v1, v2))
```